# Regex: String match including punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, match

[From another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49718320), I have this expression to match words in a sentence:

```js
var sentence = "Exclamation! Question? Full stop. Ellipsis...";
console.log(sentence.toLowerCase().match(/\w+(?:'\w+)*/g));
```

It works perfectly. However, now I am looking for a way to match exclamation marks, question marks, and full stops separately. The result should look like this:

```
[
  "exclamation",
  "!",
  "question",
  "?",
  "full",
  "stop",
  ".",
  "ellipsis",
  "."
]
```

Only matching one dot from the ellipsis, not all three dots separately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `\w+|[!?.]` what you want?

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you but not quite, I only want to match the first ellipsis, not all dots separately

Comment: Also, that version doesn't work with words containing apostrophes, such as "doesn't", "wouldn't", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a word boundary to only return one dot from the ellipsis?

```js
var sentence = "Exclamation! Question? Full stop. Ellipsis...";
console.log(sentence.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]+(?:'[a-z]+)*|\b[!?.]/g));
```

Or a negative lookahead:

```js
var sentence = "Exclamation! Question? Full stop. Ellipsis...";
console.log(sentence.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]+(?:'[a-z]+)*|[!?.](?![!?.])/g));
```

After your commented scenario extension, a negative lookbehind seems to be effective.

```js
var sentence = "You're \"Pregnant\"??? How'd This Happen?! The vasectomy YOUR 1 job. Let's \"talk this out\"...";
console.log(sentence.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z\d]+(?:'[a-z\d]+)*|(?<![!?.])[!?.]/g));
```

Comment: @MysteryPancake If you have fringe cases that break my pattern please update your question and leave me a comment.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about negative lookahead, thanks for reminding.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you so much, this works perfectly! Just one small request - would it be possible for this to work for numbers as well? Do I just need to replace `[a-z]` with `\w`?

Comment: Also, would it be possible for it to match [!?.] after quotes, such as `'text'.`, `"text"?` or `'text'!`. This may be a bit too complicated, sorry

Comment: Perhaps a negative lookbehind will serve your purposes.  I added another demo with a new pattern and sample string.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you so much, yet again! Everything appears to work perfectly now. Sorry for a dumb question, but I am just wondering, what is the difference between [a-z\d] and \w? Is there a reason you are using that instead?

Comment: `\w` includes underscores (with numbers and letters).  I am sacrificing pattern brevity for pattern accuracy / pattern intent.  You can use `\w` if you wish. Actually, because of the conversion to lowercase, I'll drop the `i` pattern modifier at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Try Below Code

```js
var sentence = "Exclamation! Question? Full stop. Ellipsis...";
console.log(sentence.toLowerCase().match(/[?!.]|\w+/g));
```

In case You want only one dot, you could use something like ---

```js
var sentence = "Exclamation!!! Question??? Full stop. Ellipsis...";

var arr = sentence.toLowerCase().match(/[?]+|[!]+|[.]+|\w+/g);
arr = arr.map(function(item){
 return item.replace(/(.)\1+/g, "$1");
})

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you, almost, but I only want the first ellipsis to be matched, not all dots after it

Comment: I have Edited my answer now it sholud work for you @MysteryPancake

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I keep bothering you, but I was really hoping it could be done with regular expressions only. I might wait for another answer since I am awful at regex