# Invalid regex group (reverse lookahead) in Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I have a rather confusing regex expression to [match words and punctuation within a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576619/regex-string-match-including-punctuation):

```js
var sentence = "Exclamation! Question? Full stop. Ellipsis...";
var words = sentence.toLowerCase().match(/\w+(?:'\w+)*|(?<![!?.])[!?.]/g);
console.log(words);
```

In Chrome, this outputs:

`[ "exclamation", "!", "question", "?", "full", "stop", ".", "ellipsis", "." ]`

In Firefox, this expression causes an error which seems to be due to the reverse lookahead.

I was wondering if it would be possible to rewrite this expression in a way which will work in Firefox, or if there is any other way in which I could accomplish this?

Comment: mozila doesn't support lookbehind yet

Comment: I am aware of this. I am hoping to find a way which does not involve the lookbehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead instead

```
\w+(?:'\w+)*|[!?.](?![!?.])
```

```js
var sentence = "Exclamation! Question? Full stop. Ellipsis...";
var words = sentence.toLowerCase().match(/\w+(?:'\w+)*|[!?.](?![!?.])/g);
console.log(words);
```